# Python: browser not opening in client side using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I developed an application using Selenium WebDriver for opening some pages. It's perfectly working locally but I need to launch the browser in client side as well.

I deployed the application using `Apache2` under `Ubuntu 18`.

```html
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver",chrome_options=chromeOptions)

# Specify the URL.
url = "www.google.com"
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Please be more specific; what have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: And what happens when you try to run it? Is there an error? Does the script run successfully and the browser window just never opens? Is chrome installed and/or the chromedriver EXE accessible to the script?

Comment: I have no error except the 504 gateway timeout. chrome is installed and chromedriver also but on the server (machine where i have the application)

Comment: Logically speaking, wouldn't you need chrome and chromedriver installed on the client-side in order for it to run client-side?

Answer (score 0):

download chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) 
**then extract /user/bin**

if you have problem fro import selenium view this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtVQ4Nui4l8)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.quit()
```